# Dealing with roles cross projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

This is one of the very important questions that I faced when I was doing the GCP data engineer practice exam:

As your organization expands its usage of GCP, many teams have started to create their own projects.
Projects are further multiplied to accommodate different stages of deployments and target
audiences. Each project requires unique access control configurations. The central IT team needs to
have access to all projects. Furthermore, data from Cloud Storage buckets and BigQuery datasets
must be shared for use in other projects in an ad hoc way. You want to simplify access control
management by minimizing the number of policies. Which two steps should you take? Choose 2
answers.

A. Use Cloud Deployment Manager to automate access provision.

B. Introduce resource hierarchy to leverage access control policy inheritance.

C. Create distinct groups for various teams, and specify groups in Cloud IAM policies.

D. Only use service accounts when sharing data for Cloud Storage buckets and BigQuery datasets.

E. For each Cloud Storage bucket or BigQuery dataset, decide which projects need access. Find all the
active members who have access to these projects, and create a Cloud IAM policy to grant access to
all these users.

According to this [1](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations)  A,B and C are all correct, but it seems we must choose only two of the options. So I was wondering what the correct answers are?

Comment: The correct answers are B and C. The key to this question is "You want to simplify access control management by minimizing the number of policies.". Deployment Manager is primarily used for creating related resources.

Comment: @John Hanley Please post answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answers are B and C. The key to this question is "You want to simplify access control management by minimizing the number of policies.". Deployment Manager is primarily used for creating related resources

Answer (score 0):

A - Deployment manager used for automating the creation of resources
(Eliminated)

B - Looks correct (as it's recommended to use hierarchy)

C - Create groups - Correct and recommended way to create groups.

D - Does not look correct (because then data will need to access only via an application) and nothing as such mention in question.

E - is more overhead and not recommended to give access to all users (but we need to simplify) - So eliminated. (but recommended to create groups)

```
So, B & C looks correct
```